# Not eunning after added .net core 2,1 (standard) library to a .net framework solution

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

I have a full .net version MVC client and accedently added a reference to a .net standard 2,1 library. When I removed the reference I got tis error and the MVC client is not runninga nymore :/

Any ideas??

[image]

Comment: do right click on the project and select `edit project file` and see if you have any PackageReference to .net standard

Comment: also check the value of `TargetFramework`

Comment: No reference (i am able to find) to .net standard. FrameworkTargetVersion in v4.6.1